# Tensorflow.Keras Adam Optimizer Instantiation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

While training CNN, I found that loss is reduced faster
when the optimizer is set as *optimizer instance*

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), 
       .......
```

then when the optimizer is set as  *String (name of optimizer)*

```
`model.compile(optimizer='adam', .......)
```

Since default `learning_rate=0.001`, why they are working differently, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically there should not be any differences. If you follow the `adam` string parameter in the source file [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8077fe8b1b4a3c170a94b74d8c351c247e64a53c/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizers.py#L83), you would see

```
all_classes = {
     'adam': adam_v2.Adam,
      ...
}
```

This `adam_v2.Adam` has linked with three implementations placed in **three** different places, i.e

1. [Source Code](http://@tf_export(%22tpu.experimental.embedding.Adam%22)%20class%20Adam(_Optimizer):) `tensorflow/python/tpu/tpu_embedding_v2_utils.py`

```
- @tf_export("tpu.experimental.embedding.Adam")
class Adam(_Optimizer):
```

2. [Source Code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8077fe8b1b4a3c170a94b74d8c351c247e64a53c/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v1.py#L464) `tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v1.py`

```
class Adam(Optimizer):
```

3. [Source Code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8077fe8b1b4a3c170a94b74d8c351c247e64a53c/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/adam.py#L34) `tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/adam.py`

```
@keras_export('keras.optimizers.Adam')
class Adam(optimizer_v2.OptimizerV2):
```

Now, check the source code of [`tf.keras.optimizers.Adam`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam), click **view source on GitHub** button, you would redirect to [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/adam.py#L34-L253) - which is number **3** from above.