# Arguments as string vs class

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In `Tensorflow`, for example the loss in `compile` can for example be `mae` or `tf.keras.losses.mae`.

Is any difference in performance or something else?
How does it work that arguments can be strings or classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the **String Identifier (SI)** that represents corresponding classes or functions. So, there wouldn't be any performance gap issue. When we use **SI**, the API calls the appropriate classes for computation, nothing mystical. Check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8077fe8b1b4a3c170a94b74d8c351c247e64a53c/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizers.py#L80-L88) for one instance:

```
 all_classes = {
      'adadelta': adadelta_v2.Adadelta,
      'adagrad': adagrad_v2.Adagrad,
      'adam': adam_v2.Adam,
      'adamax': adamax_v2.Adamax,
      'nadam': nadam_v2.Nadam,
      'rmsprop': rmsprop_v2.RMSprop,
      'sgd': gradient_descent_v2.SGD,
      'ftrl': ftrl.Ftrl,
```

Also, check the following two mutual questions and answers, it will clarify it more.

- [Non-Identical results from String Identifier and Actual Class names for activations, loss functions, and metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67063843/non-identical-results-from-string-identifier-and-actual-class-names-for-activati/67138368#67138368)
- [Tensorflow.Keras Adam Optimizer Instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66735738/tensorflow-keras-adam-optimizer-instantiation/66738863#66738863)